# Skip identical values in nestled for loops

Tags: bash, for

I want to create directories in bash by iterating over values from multiple loops (here for simplicity just 2) while skipping identical values. A demonstrating example looks like this:

`for i in 1 2 3; do for j in 1 2 3; do mkdir $i$j; done, done`

This gives me folders named `11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23, 31, 32, 33`, but I want to have only folders with different digits, so `11`, `22` and `33` should not exist. Is there a convenient for loop option to skip identical values?

Alternatively one could also create all folders and delete those with multiple values afterwards, but this seems very inefficient if there are multiple loops with many entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: The loops below run from 1 to 9 using brace expansions.  Use `{1..3}` or `1 2 3` to do *exactly* as in the question.

Compare `$i` and `$j` to make sure that they are different before creating the directory:

```
for i in {1..9}; do
    for j in {1..9}; do
        [ "$i" -ne "$j" ] && mkdir "$i$j"
    done
done
```

The `-ne` test tests for arithmetic inequality.  If you are looping over strings, use `!=` instead.  If the test is true (`$i` and `$j` are different), the directory is created with `mkdir`.

`[ "$i" -ne "$j" ] && mkdir "$i$j"` is a short-cut way of writing

```
if [ "$i" -ne "$j" ]; then
    mkdir "$i$j"
fi
```

---

To delete all directories that have names like `11`, `22` etc.:

```
for i in {1..9}; do
    rmdir "$i$i"
done
```

This assumes that the directories are empty.  Use `rm -rf "$i$i"` if they are not empty.